# multiple lines chart of X_train, X_test, Y_pred using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I am doing a project stock market prediction but I am stuck in getting all the X_train, X_test and Y_pred on a single graph something like this [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMSIr.png)

I am doing this after using the algorithm randomforestregressor

My df.head() looks like this

```
    timestamp   open    high    low         close   volume
0   2019-04-12  199.20  200.14  196.2100    198.87  27736755
1   2019-04-11  200.85  201.00  198.4431    198.95  20900808
2   2019-04-10  198.68  200.74  198.1800    200.62  21695288
3   2019-04-09  200.32  202.85  199.2300    199.50  35768237
4   2019-04-08  196.42  200.23  196.3400    200.10  25881697
```

Here is what I am doing to get the output something like this [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMSIr.png) but I am not getting anything in the graph.

**Code:**

```
plt.plot(x=df['timestamp'], y = df['close'], style = 'b-', grid = True)
plt.plot(x=df['timestamp'], y = df['close'], style = 'r-', grid = True)
plt.plot(x=df['timestamp'], y = df['close'], style = 'g-', grid = True)
plt.legend(['X_train', 'X_test', 'Y_pred'])
plt.xlabel("date")
plt.ylabel("USD")
```

**output**:

`Text(0,0.5,'USD')`

[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47dZi.png)

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use `plot_date` (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html) instead of `plot`? Also, you do realize you are plotting three times the same data?